# ConTeXt: First section head takes font formatting, but not subsequent

Tags: fonts, sectioning, context

I'm having a problem formatting section heads. The first header in the document is using the font as directed in "setuphead" but all following section heads are not.

```
\definefontfamily[meta][serif][MetaSerifOT-Book]
\definefontfamily[platform][sans][Platform]
\definefontfamily[simplon][sans][Simplon-BP]

% Set the font for all standard body text
\setupbodyfont[meta,10pt]

\definehead
    [otisection]
    [section]
\setuphead
    [section]
    [textstyle={\switchtobodyfont[platform,28pt]},
    number=no,
    align=middle,
    after={\BlueRule{}},
    ]

\starttext
\section{The First Section}
\input knuth
\section{The Second Section}
\input bryson
\section{Third Section}
\input knuth
\stoptext
```

This script gives a first section in Platform 28pt but all subsequent sections in MetaSerif, 10pt. Any advice?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You are using commercial fonts and custom macros.  Please always make sure to use fonts which are publicly available and include your macro definitions, so it is easier for people to reproduce your problem and help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typescript used with `\switchtobodyfont` must be used in global scope for the first time. When you compile the file, the console shows the following hint:

```
structure       > sectioning > section @ level 3 : 0.0.1 -> The First Section
fonts           > bodyfont '28pt' is defined (can better be done global)
fonts           > bodyfont '33.6pt' is defined (can better be done global)
fonts           > bodyfont '22.4pt' is defined (can better be done global)
```

One fix is to use the typescript in a global scope once.

```
\definefontfamily[meta][serif][Times New Roman]
\definefontfamily[platform][sans][Arial]

\setupbodyfont[platform,28pt]
\setupbodyfont[meta,10pt]


\setuphead
    [section]
    [textstyle={\switchtobodyfont[platform,28pt]},
    number=no,
    align=middle,
    ]

\starttext
\section{The First Section}
\input knuth
\section{The Second Section}
\input bryson
\section{Third Section}
\input knuth
\stoptext
```

I substituted common fonts because I did not have the ones that you were using.

[image]

Having said that, I think that the current behaviour is a bug and should be reported on the context mailing list.

Answer (score 4):

You have to define the font first and then use it.  `\switchtobodyfont` is not the right tool in here.  Unfortunately, I have none of the fonts you are using, so I substituted them by some default ones.  Also the definition for `\BlueRule` is missing in your example, but it is irrelevant so I removed it.

See [»Fonts out of ConTeXt«](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/fonts-mkiv.pdf) for details.

```
\setupbodyfont[pagella,10pt]
\definefont[SectionFont][name:heros at 28pt]

\setuphead
  [section]
  [
    textstyle={\SectionFont},
    number=no,
    align=middle,
  ]

\starttext
\section{The First Section}
\input knuth
\section{The Second Section}
\input bryson
\section{Third Section}
\input knuth
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you say that `\switchtobodyfont` is not the right tool? I personally prefer `\switchtobodyfont` instead of `\definefont` for section titles (even though the former is slower) because it does a complete typeface switch. This is important when your headings could contain math or `\type{..}`. Try adding some math in the section title in your example.

Comment: @Aditya You have a point.  I updated my answer.

Comment: @Aditya Oops.  Now our answers are the same.  I will roll back.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that the immediately after I pressed enter. Don't revert your edits! If it is okay with you, we can merge our answer (by adding the details about the hint in the console in your answer).

Comment: @Aditya Nevermind.  This is not a competition.  Now we have two correct answers and can let OP decide which one is "correct".